# MUI v5 - Styled() and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using MUI v5 and decided to migrate from makeStyles to styled() utility function. I have this styled div:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/system";

export const WelcomeDiv = styled("div")({
  background: "blue",
});
```

I try to import it use it this way:

```
  return (
    <WelcomeDiv>
    </WelcomeDiv>
  );
```

Thing is, I've just started using typescript and not sure how to implement it.

Comment: What's the issue? does the component not show? is there any type error?

Comment: Error: property 'divLoginPage' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'

Comment: Can you put your code on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicusage-material-demo-forked-cgcmf?file=/demo.tsx)?